# How can I remove enter signs small squares after pasting code from FormUser?

Tags: excel, vba

I created a UserForm and inside I created a TextBox. I set MultiLine as True and set EnterKeyBehavior as True. Then using VBA I wanted to pasted the code in a cell:

```
Range("A8").Activate
ActiveCell.Value=UserForm1.TextBox1.Text
```

After pasting I see after each line in place when I put enter in a TextBox a smallboxes. I tried to remove them in many ways but I couldn't. I searched a solution over the Interned and I tried a lot of things but it still does't work.

[image]

Comment: Did you try the Replace command?

Comment: Yes. When I copy a sign from a cell and try to use "find and replace", I can't paste it.
Excel paste it as a enter but without a small box and that is why I can't replace it. I use Excel 2007 and Windows XP